# After Google Chrome update Sencha Touch spins

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.2

After I updated my Google Chrome to the newest version (`v29.0.1547.57 m`), some parts of the Sencha Touch app spin. I am using Sencha Touch `v2.2.1`.

For instance `Ext.Msg.Alert`, I get the title but no message.

`Ext.Msg.alert('Refreshing Session', 'test', null);`
[image: Ext.Msg.Alert]

Also all of my buttons in `Ext.navigation.View` are on the left side, even I said explicitly `align: 'right'`

The title of `Ext.navigation.View` is also empty, even I set it.

I have changed nothing in my code. With the old version of Google Chrome `v28.0.1500.95` everything worked and is still working perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also experienced Problems and this quick fix from sencha forum resolved it for me:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?269123-2.2.1-default-app.css-amp-chromium-blink-problem&p=987612&viewfull=1#post987612>

Replace mixin st-box and recompile css

```
@mixin st-box($important: no) {
@if $important == important {
    display: flex !important;
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
} @else {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
}
}
```

Comment: You can just download the `v2.2.1`. The fixed, built and uploaded it.

Comment: Updated from 2.2.1(.480) to 2.2.1(.2) and it fixed it.

Comment: Follow this link 
http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/fix-chrome-29-breaks-all-sencha-touch-2-apps/#comment-148934